# Как удалить определенное количество символов из строки ? Python

Tags: python, строки

Всем привет . Я столкнулся с такой вот проблемой : У меня есть строка , допустим такая -

```
'\n\n\n\xa0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\nKП\n\nДанный\n\nзаходил\n\n\n .'
```

Мне надо получить слово ЗАХОДИЛ или любой другое на его месте, то есть нужно обрезать строку , но обрезать конкретные символы нельзя ,т.к слово Данный в этой строке ,так же принимает различные значения . Так вот возможно ли обрезать строку ,например, на 20 символов и если возможно подскажите как. Заранее спасибо !

Answer (score 3):

Дополнение к ответам:

```
txt = '\n\n\n\xa0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\nKП\n\nДанный\n\nзаходил\n\n\n .'.strip()
print(txt)
```

```
KП

Данный

заходил


 .
```

```
txt = [x for x in txt.split() if x]
print(txt)
```

```
['KП', 'Данный', 'заходил', '.']
```

```
print(txt[2])
```

```
заходил
```

```
print(' '.join(txt))
```

```
KП Данный заходил .
```

Comment: Ну это не дополнение, это как раз самое нормальное решение. Лучше использовать split, и сразу убрать все повторяющиеся переносы, а не срезами куски отпиливать.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте срез для задачи "обрезать строку ,например, на 20 символов". Пример:

```
a= '\n\n\n\xa0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\nKП\n\nДанный\n\nзаходил\n\n\n'
print (a[20:])
```

Вывод:

```
Данный

заходил
```

Что почитать:
https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил поставленный вопрос - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Answer (score 1):

Можно обрезать через срез:

```
string = '\n\n\n\xa0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\nKП\n\nДанный\n\nзаходил\n\n\n .'
string[19:]
```

Получится:

```
'KП\n\nДанный\n\nзаходил\n\n\n .'
```

Если `КП\n\n` не нужно:

```
string[23:]
```

Получится:

```
'Данный\n\nзаходил\n\n\n .'
```

Comment: Катерина, какой смысл размещать в базе знаний идентичный ответ? Я же уже написал про срез. Хочется что-то ответить - предложите другой вариант, опишите его. Тут же много разных решений может быть.

Comment: @Сергей Мы отправили с вами фактически одновременно, и я не могу читать мысли незнакомых мне людей, ответит ли кто-то так же как и я, пока пишу ответ, к тому же в срезе вы указали не совсем корректный индекс. Так что не нужно устраивать холивар и обиды. Вашу идею я не украла, поверьте.

Comment: 1) Ошибка у вас - проверьте на коротком примере, например, `a= '12345'. Индекс жe у меня корректен - надо именно [20:] для удаления 20 символов,которые просят.    2) У вас размещение шло позже, видно по времени. Подтверждая размещение, видно, что уже есть ответы. Но дело и право ваше. (Как и право размещать информацию о себе на русскоязычном форуме на английском, да ещё и не очень идеальном:-) Но любовь к Python - это хорошо:-)

Comment: @Сергей сколько же токсичности и зачем... По поводу моей ошибки - просто скопируйте его строку и сделайте срез сами, он попросил срез с "Данных", указала срезы как с "Данных", так и с "КП".  Спасибо, что оценили оформление моего профиля. ;) Хорошего вечера

Comment: Катерина, у меня нет токсичности, поверьте. Срез - никак не изобретение века, сильно ответом не горжусь:-) Если задел - извините. Для того и эмотиконы ставил, чтобы мягче выглядело. Мои комментарии нацелены на соответствие цели и правилам сайта (как и десятки других моих комментариев при проверках ответов). Как относительно базы знаний, так и русскоязычности.

Comment: @Сергей Срез - это просто первое, что придет на ум любому человеку, читая этот вопрос. Моя цель была помочь человеку, написать рабочий код под его пример. Вы меня не задели, но не совсем ясно, как описание моего профиля, созданное более 4 лет назад, касается вопроса. :) Если бы не вы, даже не вспомнила, что там написано :))))))

Comment: Про описание - логика проста: "Мои комментарии нацелены на соответствие цели и правилам сайта". Так как писал про одно, то сразу упомянул и про другое.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё короче, чем было предложено. Параметр разбиения у функции `split` по умолчанию именно такой, какой нужно - любые пробельные символы:

```py
text = '\n\n\n\xa0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\nKП\n\nДанный\n\nзаходил\n\n\n .'
print(' '.join(text.split()[1:]))
```

Вывод:

```
Данный заходил .
```

Comment: Автор просил и "КП" убрать, как я понимаю.